Convert sciBERT to GGUF
I want to use the SciBERT weights in Ollama. Ollama accepts GGUF format, whereas SciBERT is in another format. I downloaded SciBERT from this huggingface link. I tried to convert it with llama.cpp conversion tool, which produces the error:
python convert-hf-to-gguf.py /mnt/d/ai-models --outfile /mnt/d/ai-models/output_file.gguf
INFO:hf-to-gguf:Loading model: ai-models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert-hf-to-gguf.py", line 2548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert-hf-to-gguf.py", line 2526, in main
    model_class = Model.from_model_architecture(hparams["architectures"][0])
KeyError: 'architectures'

Similarly, convert.py from llama.cpp cannot recognize format of the model:
python convert.py /mnt/d/ai-models --outfile /mnt/d/ai-models/output_file.gguf
INFO:convert:Loading model file /mnt/d/ai-models/pytorch_model.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1714, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1630, in main
    model_plus = load_some_model(args.model)
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1474, in load_some_model
    models_plus.append(lazy_load_file(path))
  File "/mnt/d/llama.cpp/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1025, in lazy_load_file
    raise ValueError(f"unknown format: {path}")
ValueError: unknown format: /mnt/d/ai-models/pytorch_model.bin

Do I use the conversion command in a wrong way or is it not capable to convert the format of SciBERT? How to convert SciBERT to the GGUF format?
